# What was the purpose behind Daphne collecting data on the wizards?

Tags: fairy-tail

In the Fairy Tail anime, what was the purpose behind Daphne collecting data on the wizards? Was it just to keep them busy fighting the Lizardmen while she destroyed Magnolia, or was she planning on using the data in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that she was collecting data on wizards so she can find a dragon slayer worthy of her invention (the fake non-working dragon, i'd like to call it) to make it work and show the people back in her village that dragons are real and that she was not lying when she told them that she saw one.

And for the lizard men, I believe that she used them to distract the Fairy Tail wizards and focus on putting Natsu in her invention using Gray, so it can work. And I believe that she did not want to destroy Magnolia and do some evil stuff. She just wanted to prove that dragons are real.